# Is #file considered a literal String in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, literals

Bug **>** Swift **>** Enum **>** String Protocol

---

I was attempting to create an enumeration in which all its elements were file names, and I stumbled across something interesting. Like so:

```
enum FileNames: String {
     case main = #file
}
```

This resulted in an internal error. (Segmentation Fault: 11)

---

I was able to figure how to get an actual error message:

```
enum Foo: String {
    case one = "\(1)"
}
```

`Error: Raw value for enum case must be a literal`

---

**Related Questions:**
• Is `#file` considered a String literal?
• Why does `#file` break the enum? Should this be reported on bugs.swift.org?
• I noticed that replacing `String` to `Int` and `#file` to `#line` causes the same issue. Is this a hint?

---

## Color Literals Don't Work

I thought they did, but I made a mistake. It also causes the same internal error.

```
import UIKit

enum ColorEnum: UIColor {
    case foo = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
}
```

---

## The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.2)

According to Apple, `#file` is considered a literal:

[image: #file is described as a literal according to Apple]

---

## What about nil Literals?

These also crash the compiler.

```
enum Foo: String? {
    case breaks = nil
}
```

---

23 Characters of Mass Destruction
`enum I:Int?{case a=nil}`

---

## Bug Fixed

The crash has now been fixed, it has been merged officially into Swift here: [Merged on GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/32364)
Here's the bug report: [SR-12998](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12998?jql=project%20%3D%20SR%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug). It has officially been implemented in Swift 5.4

**Adding Support!**
The use of magic literals as raw values for enum cases is being supported here: [SR-13022](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13022)

Comment: Seems like you can file a bug just on the basis of that segfault. Apple might settle the spec question (they could add 'special literals aren't usable in X, Y, and Z' and a diagnostic or say "yeah we should make it work"). You may or may not get a sense whether any fix is coming soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, `#file` and `#line` are *literal expressions* but your program is still ill-formed.**

The Swift language reference [says](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID390):

> A literal expression consists of either an ordinary literal (such as a string or a number), an array or dictionary literal, a playground literal, or one of the following special literals:
>
> `#file` — String — The name of the file in which it appears.
>
> `#line` — Int — The line number on which it appears.
>
> [...]

Let's also note the grammar:

```
literal-expression → literal
literal-expression → array-literal | dictionary-literal | playground-literal
literal-expression → #file | #line | #column | #function | #dsohandle
```

Now let us consider the [grammar of the enum](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_raw-value-style-enum-member) you are defining. I am only including the most relevant parts here you can verify the complete deduction yourself:

```
enum-declaration → attributes opt access-level-modifier opt raw-value-style-enum
[...]
raw-value-style-enum → enum enum-name generic-parameter-clause opt type-inheritance-clause generic-where-clause opt { raw-value-style-enum-members }
[...]
raw-value-assignment → = raw-value-literal
raw-value-literal → numeric-literal | static-string-literal | boolean-literal
```

It's noteworthy that only [*numeric-literal*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#grammar_numeric-literal), [*static-string-literal*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#grammar_static-string-literal), [*boolean-literal*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#grammar_numeric-literal) are allowed. If we look at their definitions, it's clear that those `#`literals thus do not match the `raw-value-literal` rule:

```
numeric-literal → -opt integer-literal | -opt floating-point-literal
boolean-literal → true | false
```

```
static-string-literal → string-literal-opening-delimiter quoted-text opt string-literal-closing-delimiter
static-string-literal → multiline-string-literal-opening-delimiter multiline-quoted-text opt multiline-string-literal-closing-delimiter
```

All relevant rules for completely defining *static-string-literal* are long, but it's still trivial to see that *static-string-literal* cannot be deduced to `#file` and cannot include interpolation. (That's what makes it static.)

So the Swift compiler is indeed right in refusing your program. Still, a modern compiler shouldn't simply crash on an illegal program, so it might be worth reporting this issue.

Comment: This is amazing insight. Now I know why single quote Strings are also not allowed. This inspired me to conform a struct to ```ExpressibleByNilLiteral```, let the enum conform to the Struct, and set the raw value of one of the cases to be ```nil```. It causes the same internal error, so I will definitely report it.

Comment: Actually just doing this breaks as well: ```enum I:Int?{case a=nil}```

Comment: @Jonathan I don’t think nil is a raw value literal, so that’s the same issue basically.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a bug, so worth submitting feedback to Apple (although they documented that those #file, #function, etc. are *special literals*)

Anyway, probably the following workaround can be helpful in some use-cases:

```
enum FileNames {
    static let main = FileNames.file(#file)
    case file(String)
}
```

Comment: This is a smart work-a-round! Unfortunately the compiler gets confused from finding 2 candidates named ```main```, but I think this will point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.4 fixes the crash

Swift 5.4 implements the bugfix from [SR-12998](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12998?jql=project%20%3D%20SR%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug)

Instead of the compiler crashing, it now displays descriptive error messages:

---

Magic Literals from Strings

```swift
enum Foo: String {
    // Compiler Error: Use of '#file' literal as raw value for enum case is not supported
    case b = #file
    // Compiler Error: Use of '#function' literal as raw value for enum case is not supported
    case c = #function
}
```

Magic Literals from Ints

```swift
enum B: Int {
    // Compiler Error: Use of '#line' literal as raw value for enum case is not supported
    case b = #line
    // Compiler Error: Use of '#column' literal as raw value for enum case is not supported
    case c = #column
}
```

Magic Literals from UnsafeRawPointers

```swift
extension UnsafeRawPointer: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {}
enum Wo: UnsafeRawPointer {
    // Compiler Error: Use of '#dsohandle' literal as raw value for enum case is not supported
    case wo = #dsohandle
}
```

Using the Magic Literal `nil` in this way now displays a different error instead of crashing the compiler.

```swift
enum Foo: String? {
    case breaks = nil
}
enum I:Int?{case a=nil}
```

---

#### It's not completely fixed:

However, the magic literal `nil` still can cause the compiler to crash:

```swift
extension Optional: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral where Wrapped == Int {}
enum Foo: Int? {
    // Compiler Crashes: Segmentation fault: 11
    case c = nil
}
```

Also the magic literal for UIColor still cause the compiler to crash:

```swift
import UIKit
extension UIColor: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {}
enum ColorEnum: UIColor {
    // Compiler Crashes: Segmentation fault: 11
    case foo = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
}
```